# What is the current best-practice way to configure a Wifi station under Debian Jessie command line?

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, beaglebone

There seams to be much conflicting advice as the the *right* way to configure a Wifi station from the command line under recent versions of Debian. Which way is best-practice and why?

Should the SSID and password be stored in `/etc/network/interfaces` or in `wpa-suplicant` conf file?

Or should we use `connman` to do all Wireless config as suggested by the comment in the default `\etc\network\interfaces`?

Several tutorials suggest using `iwlist show` but I only get the error `Not supported by adapter`.

Some suggest using `wicd-curses`, but this does not seem to be available in the default images.

Comment: To get some info about your wifi  card please edit by adding the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: After more testing, I am pretty sure that I've run into a real problem in the latest BBB Jessie images and I've posted that in a [new question](http://superuser.com/questions/1120862/how-to-fix-broken-wifi-in-the-most-recent-beagle-bone-jessie-images). I'm still interested in the answer to the above general question, which I've edited to remove references to the specific problems I was seeing.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with this a lot, I think that Wicd is the best way to set this up. It has the benefits that...

1. It is easy to set up with `wicd-curses` becuase you can pick form a scan of available networks rather than trying to type ESSID's and BSSID's correctly into config files.
2. It gracefully deals with automatic connection and re-connection using configurable behaviors.

The one big gotcha to using `wicd-curses` is that when you first pull it up it does not see any networks. This really through me off. The trick is that you have to enter the name of the wifi adapter into the preferences the first time.

To get the anme of the wifi adapter, type...

`iwconfig`

The wifi adapter will usually be called something like `wlanx` where `x` is a number.

Then fire up `wicd-curses` and press`P` to get to the preferences page and enter it in the `Wireless Interface` field`and press`F10` to save.

[image]

Once you do that, the scan should show you all visible networks and you can pick the one you want. Also be sure to check the `Connect Automatically` if that's what you want (it is always what I want)...

[image]

Once these steps are done, the baord should automatically connect to wifi on booting, and reconnect is the network drops and then comes back.